# PHP DomCrawler ,Get child node based on a specific parent

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, domcrawler

Get child node based on a specific parent

```
function(Crawler $node,){
    $node->filter('this>ul');
}
```

How can I get a `$node` children，that does not contain a grandson like the CSS selector `#parent>child` ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using CSS selector.
2. There aren't any `this` or `parent` selector in CSS.
3. You should use just `$node->filter('>ul');`

Comment: I tried, no good;
error:Expected selector, but <delimiter ">" at 0> found.

Comment: I found that `filter` or `filterXPath` returns only the first occurence.
So even if you have ul, and descendant children, it doesn't matter cause you will get only the first one, the parent.
If you want to match only empty ul, you have to use `ul:empty` selector.

Comment: filter:Filters the list of nodes with a CSS selector.

Comment: Although the problem is not resolved, but still thank you ; maybe I should learn about XPath

Comment: @michail_w I've found that filter returns all the occurrences. I've always just needed to loop through them. Ex. `$items_out = $crawler->filter('span.item_title');
    $items_out->each(function ($node) {
     echo '<pre>';
  print $node->text()."\n";
  echo '</pre>';
 });`